# wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsGeometry has been deleted ubuntu and mac and segmentation fault

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, error

I have a problem with a specific method in qgis 2.8, 2.12 and 2.12.1 on linux and mac (I have not idea if in windows this problem persists)

The example:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from ceamos.utils import *
from ceamos.config import *

def run_script(iface):

    #remove all layers
    clearAll(iface)

    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(project_path + '/qgis_data/area.shp',
                          'laflorida',
                          vectorLayerType.ogr)

    assert lyr.isValid()

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([lyr]) 
    geom = lyr.getFeatures().next().geometry()
    print geom # <qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x7f3a08715510>

    print geom.contains(QgsPoint(0,0)) # RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsGeometry has been deleted
```

Update 25-DIC-2015

I have changed the code to

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from ceamos.utils import *
from ceamos.config import *

def run_script(iface):

    #remove all layers
    clearAll(iface)

    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(project_path + '/qgis_data/area.shp',
                          'laflorida',
                          vectorLayerType.ogr)

    assert lyr.isValid()

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([lyr]) 
    #geom = lyr.getFeatures().next().geometry()
    geom = QgsGeometry(lyr.getFeatures().next().geometry())
    print geom # <qgis._core.QgsGeometry object at 0x7f3a08715510>

    # RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsGeometry has been deleted 
    #print geom.contains(QgsPoint(0,0)) #Segmentation fault

    feat = lyr.getFeatures().next() #Segmentation fault
    #print feat.geometry().contains(QgsPoint(0,0))
```

But in the line `feat = lyr.getFeatures().next()` I got a segmentation fault error (in mac and ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be [bug #777](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/777)

Try

```
feat = lyr.getFeatures().next()
feat.geometry().contains(QgsPoint(0,0))
```

Comment: in have segmetation fault in the line **geom = QgsGeometry(lyr.getFeatures().next().geometry())**

Comment: Updated, does it work now?

Comment: with the update I have a segmentation fault in **feat = lyr.getFeatures().next()**

Comment: I have update the post with your suggestions and the new error